# How to retrieve current user details using provider package?

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I want to use fetch user details from firestore data tree eg:

```
- "Users"
   - user.uid
       - name
       - age
```

using provider package.

Then I can user username or age value globally in app. Can anyone please provide a code example for this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check out [this article](https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-firebase-realtime-database-crud-operations-using-provider-c242a01f6a10).

Comment: Thanks, It helped me much. https://medium.com/flutter-community/firebase-startup-logic-and-custom-user-profiles-6309562ea8b7 has more answer on profile page on flutter app